# Process in timebench

Tags: signals, vhdl, test-bench

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

entity equation_tb is
end equation_tb;

architecture Behavioral of equation_tb is
    signal x, y, z, t, w : std_logic;
    signal F             : std_logic;
    
begin
    UUT : entity work.equation port map (x, y, z, t, w, F);
    process
    begin
    x <= '0', '1' after 160 ns;
    y <= '0', '1' after 80 ns, '0' after 160 ns, '1' after 240 ns; 
    z <= '0', '1' after 40 ns, '0' after 80 ns, '1' after 120 ns, '0' after 160 ns, '1' after 200 ns, '0' after 240 ns, '1' after 280 ns; 
    t <= '0', '1' after 20 ns, '0' after 40 ns, '1' after 60 ns, '0' after 80 ns, '1' after 100 ns, '0' after 120 ns, '1' after 140 ns, '0' after 160 ns, '0' after 180 ns, '1' after 200 ns, '0' after 220 ns, '1' after 240 ns, '0' after 260 ns, '1' after 280 ns, '0' after 300 ns;
    end process;

end Behavioral;
```

Hello, is there any way to write this in a simpler way. After "t" I have to write this for "w" and it will change in every 10ns, hence the line will be very long.

I tought about using for loop or if, but couldn't know what to do.

Comment: Seems like something a for loop could help - looks like each iteration waits another chunk of time? https://vhdlwhiz.com/for-loop/

Comment: You do not need a process here.   If you use a process, add  `wait ;` before the `end process;` - otherwise you have an infinite loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use separate processes for each signal. Since each process without a blocking `wait` will be repeated, this gives you cyclical signals as you want.

```vhdl
architecture Behavioral of equation_tb is
    signal x : std_logic := '0';
    signal y : std_logic := '0';
    signal z : std_logic := '0';
    signal t : std_logic := '0';
    signal w : std_logic := '0';
    signal F : std_logic;
    
begin
    UUT : entity work.equation port map (x, y, z, t, w, F);

    process
    begin
        wait for 160 ns;
        x <= not x;
    end process;

    process
    begin
        wait for 80 ns;
        y <= not y;
    end process;

    process
    begin
        wait for 40 ns;
        z <= not z;
    end process;

    process
    begin
        wait for 20 ns;
        t <= not t;
    end process;

    process
    begin
        wait for 10 ns;
        w <= not w;
    end process;

end Behavioral;
```

You probably had a typo in your sequence for `t`, as you wrote `'0' after 160 ns, '0' after 180 ns`. I ignored that.

Comment: You could simplify your code if you simply used assignments to do the same thing:   `w <= not w after 10 ns;`  and so on.

Answer (score 1):

If it weren't for the extra assignment to '0' on t at 180 ns you could use aggregate assignment from a counter. I can't think of any reason to at the extra assignment to 0, all 16 binary values of the aggregate inputs are represented.

```vhdl
architecture foo of equation_tb is
    signal x, y, z, t   : std_logic := '0';
    signal w, F         : std_logic;
    use ieee.numeric_std.all;
    signal counter: unsigned (3 downto 0) := (others => '0');
begin
UUT: entity work.equation port map (x, y, z, t, w, F);

STIMULI:
    process
    begin
        for i in 0 to 15 loop
            (x, y, z, t) <= std_logic_vector(counter);
            counter <= counter + 1;
            wait for 20 ns;
        end loop;
        wait;
    end process;
end architecture;
```

Which gives:

[image: equation_tb.jpg]

This was done using a dummy entity and architecture for equation because you used a component instantiation using the reserved word `entity`.